# Is well-pointedness the reason that the internal/external distinction seems not to apply to $\mathbf{Set}$?

Tags: ct.category-theory, set-theory, topos-theory, foundations

When reasoning about the category of sets, we usually don't have to worry about the internal/external distinction. For example, if $f : X \rightarrow Y$ is a morphism of sets, then $f$ is either surjective, or not. We don't have to distinguish between being [point-surjective](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Lawvere%27s+fixed+point+theorem), versus being surjective in the internal language. And, maybe this is just because I don't do independence proofs, but personally, I've never been in a situation where I've had to say: "$\mathbf{Set}$ internally satisfies *foo*. But note that this does not hold from an external point of view." Or vice versa. My question is basically, is this equivalence between perspectives due to well-pointedness, or something deeper going on? Also can we formalize this idea that both internal and external perspectives are equivalent, or does it have to remain a vague metaprinciple?

Comment: These "internal" notions were obtained by taking some notion $A$ in $\mathbf{Set}$ and then finding a definition $B$ interpretable in an arbitrary category such that $B$ coincides with $A$ when restricted to $\mathbf{Set}$. So of course internal and external are the same for $\mathbf{Set}$.